# tsc won't produce declaration files due to false error with import.meta

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

I'm using ViteJS to compile a TS codebase. Vite has no problem transpiling the code but it doesn't handle the *types* and so I'm trying to use Typescript's **tsc** to do this and getting errors with every reference to `import.meta.env`.

I run the type build with:

```sh
npx tsc src/index.ts \
    --emitDeclarationOnly \ 
    --module es2020 \
    --target es2020 \
    --outDir dist/types
```

> Note: changing `es2020` to `esnext` also fails in the same way

I the the following error in all places where I'm using the new ES Module syntax:

> Property 'env' does not exist on type 'ImportMeta'

but in **vs-code** the type system is happy and indeed at runtime this does in fact work. Now the *reason* that vs-code is happy is that there is a `src/ImporMeta.d.ts` file which I've created that looks like this:

```
interface ImportMeta {
  env: {
    VITE_APP_TITLE?: string;
    BASE_URL: string;
    MODE: string;
    PROD: boolean;
    DEV: boolean;
    VITE_DEBUG?: boolean;
    [`VITE_${string}`]: string;
  };
}
```

For some reason, however, **tsc** is not seeing this file or refusing to build for some other reason even though the "target" and "module" are both at levels where `import.meta` should be allowed.

> [image: vs-code reports no error]

Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong?

---

I'm using Typescript **4.5.2** and running under node **16.13.0** (also tried node **14.18.1** but same results)

---

UPDATE: to my surprise, although I'm getting these errors (three of them), it still actually builds the types including for the files where the files originate ... for my CI/CD I need the errors to go away so the issue has not been resolved but now I'm confused why it would build and then fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need a custom .d.ts for this, just use the following in tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["vite/client"]
  }
}
```

Here is the corresponding docs page: https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#client-types

Note that the .d.ts file might not be picked up by tsc because the entry point you specified for the tsc command.

Comment: true you do not but as the Vite docs explain, you _can_ do it to add stronger typing. In fact, removing this file then causes my code to fail within vs-code but the **tsc** command from the command line still fails in the same manner.

Comment: also bear in mind if you use **tsc** on the command line and point to an entry point file, you do NOT use the `tsconfig.json` file and therefore this setting (which btw I _do_ have) will have zero impact.

Comment: actually, having just typed this i'm now a bit confused as apparently in all my mucking around I had actually removed this line from my `tsconfig.json` and when I put it back in the error went away. this is quite counter-intuitive but for some reason still seems to work.

Comment: Having a long roll of tsc options in a command line is not easy to maintain in my opinion, I prefer having tsconfig files for my projects. As far as I know, vscode will use the tsconfig json if it exists anyway. Also, you could use --types (https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#types) for the same purpose, or just include your .d.ts file as well with an entry point glob on the command line

Comment: oh i agree; i definitely prefer using the tsconfig.json but i need to check as I thought it wasn't picking up my "target" and "module" params when I stated an entry point. That might be wrong though as I pretty tired last night when I was looking at this.

Comment: It's intresting, for me it works when I add "config" folder that uses `import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL` into tsconfig file into include section: "include": ["src", "config"]. for Vite 4.0.4.

Comment: Yes, the file should be included in the project as well. The above lines we discussed allow TS to infer properties of `import.meta.env` that vite supports by default. I'm not sure if any of this has changed in vite v4, I'll check later and update my answer accordingly.